# Converting multiple blobs to pdf

Tags: python, file, pdf, blob, cx-oracle

I have multiple blob chunks all 28K byte size except the last one which can be same or less. x.pdf has 94 chunks. The code loops through 94 chunks and ends without error. Anybody worked with multiple blobs to create single file.

Already created 275K files using PL/SQL, now stuck with about 4K which seems too large for UTL_FILE function.

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('sysadm/password@mydb')

cur = con.cursor() 
sql = 'select count(*) from chunk_record where filename = :sfn'
cur.execute(sql, sfn = 'x.pdf')
z = cur.fetchone()[0]
y = 0
with codecs.open('x.pdf', encoding='utf-8', mode='wb+') as file:
    bcur = con.cursor()
    for y in range (z):
        print(y)
        bsql = 'select file_data from chunk_record where filename = :sfn and file_seq = :seq'
        bcur.execute(bsql, sfn = 'x.pdf', seq = y)
        if type(bcur.fetchone()[0]) is cx_Oracle.BLOB:
             file.write(bcur.fetchone()[0].read())
    bcur.close()
file.close()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Below python code is generating x.pdf with zero size. When I try to open in pdf it gives error. The size should be in between 28K*93 ~ 28K*94

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? You can try print what is being written to file first to STDOUT, this will make sure that you are getting data back from the SQL connection,

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The condition `type(row[0]) is cx_Oracle.BLOB` is always false. As `cx_Oracle.BLOB` is the column type that appears in the result 
set description but the class is `cx_Oracle.LOB` so to check for that instead:

```
row = bcur.fetchone()
if isinstance(row[0], cx_Oracle.LOB):
    file.write(row[0].read())
```

The reason the file ended up empty was that it was never written to.

The rest of the answer stands as being true.

---

Why are you opening the file with an encoding? It should be binary data that should not be transcoded.

Replace `with codecs.open('x.pdf', encoding='utf-8', mode='wb+') as file:`

With `with open('x.pdf', mode='wb+') as file:`

Comment: Dan D that was my original code, it did not work so I changed to codecs . You are right about the cx_oracle object but actual problem was multiple blobs needed attribute 'a'

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('x.pdf', mode='a') as file:
```

changing wb+ to a resolved the issue, thanks.

Comment: That this resolves part of the issue means that the code is opening and closing the file between blob writes which is something that the code I  the question isn't doing.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point. The file is opened and closed once. 'a' does the append. Python documents explain it. Or am I missing something?